# Georeference automatically thousands of scanned maps

Tags: opencv, geolocation, qgis

I need to georeference automatically thousands of scanned maps (263 inner points inside the map and some in the territory limits), all maps represent the same territory and only change some conventions. I Tried to identify contours with OpenCV and look like good parameters for machine learning and georeferencing, but i dont know how to identify an specific contourn in different images, If I succeed, I can put the georeference for that contur. ¿some ideas?, ¿other possibilities?.
Here i put two maps for clarifying the idea: [image: Mapa 1]; [image: Mapa 2]

Comment: Use openlayers 3 and GDAL Library installed with QGIS to automate georeference.